# How to set MFP_CORDOVA_HOME

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I'm using MFP 7.1 CLI with cordova, when i add a plugin to my project with :

```
mfp cordova plugin add Toast -d
```

I can see this line in the log :

> MFP_CORDOVA_PATH has not been set. using internal cordova cli

I tried to set this MFP_CORDOVA_PATH but then i have this error :

> Implementation for this cordova subcommand has failed or not been
>   provided: plugin

I'd like to upgrade the version of cordova CLI used by MFP, if someone know how to do it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to upgrade the Cordova version provided by MobileFirst in the MobileFirst CLI. However, the supplied Cordova version can be patched by IBM with any fixes that may be required (this is done on a per-case basis, for example in order to fix vulnerabilities).

I can suggest you to upgrade to the latest available CLI from IBM Fix Central (you can check for the version you are currently using by running the command `mfp -v`). Perhaps this issue is fixed there. If not, then I suggest to open a PMR (support ticket) in order for the development team to investigate and possibly provide an iFix (a build with a fix for the problem).